# Using strreplace with variables against running script?

Tags: autohotkey, self-modifying

### Update:

A lot of progress was made to the ini result and the self-editing-code result; however, only the functions that make the edits are finished, not the gui/implementation. Will add more soon.

My roommate is trying to replace a section of a script while the script is active.

### Goal:

The idea is to replace `c:\test` with `c:\new` in the file.
It might not be necessary to reload the script, but it might be necessary: we want to test this.

We tried replacing `dir` with `%dir%` and `newdir` with `%newdir%`, but that created errors.

The defaults are now showing up because they are declared (thanks Dieisson Silva dos Santos).

It might be ideal to use a gui. Any which way you can, though. Comments welcome!

Possible problems:

1. Maybe the tf_replace function is not being implemented correctly?
2. Maybe the variables from the InputBox need some kind of prefix?
3. Something else?

### Problematic code:

```ini
;; Use a GUI to change the file.
#Include %A_MyDocuments%\AutoHotKey\Lib\tf.ahk ; the a_mydocuments var needs to be written out because on many devices AHKLv1 thinks the lib directory is in C:\Program Files\Autohotkey.
#Include %A_ScriptDir%
#Include %A_ScriptFullPath% ; Necessary on some devices.
#SingleInstance Force

;; Use a GUI to change the file.
^u::
    olddir = c:\test ; Necessary for default to work in InputBox function.
    newdir = c:\new ; "".
    Gosub, updatefile ; Find all instances of %olddir% in the file and replace them with %newdir%.
    InputBox, oldDir, Edit AHK File, Insert OLD directory name., , 300, 140, , , , ,% olddir
    If ErrorLevel
        Return
    Gosub, updatefile    ; change var
    InputBox, newDir, Edit AHK File, Insert NEW directory name., , 300, 140, , , , ,% newdir
    If ErrorLevel
        Return
    Return

;; Change the file with no gui.
^d::    ; The goal of ctrl+t is to replace all instances of olddir with newdir
;olddir := "c:\test"
;newdir := "c:\new"
    updatefile:
        msgbox, % A_ScriptFullPath
        tf_replace(olddir, newdir, A_ScriptFullPath)
    Return
!f11::exitapp
```

The function is from tf.ahk (https://github.com/hi5/TF), and it is supposed to replace every occurrence of a string in file.

### Excerpt from TF.ahk by Hi5:

```ini
TF_Replace(Text, SearchText, ReplaceText="")
    {
     TF_GetData(OW, Text, FileName)
     IfNotInString, Text, %SearchText%
        Return Text ; SearchText not in TextFile so return and do nothing, we have to return Text in case of a variable otherwise it would empty the variable contents bug fix 3.3
     Loop
        {
         StringReplace, Text, Text, %SearchText%, %ReplaceText%, All
         if (ErrorLevel = 0) ; No more replacements needed.
            break
        }
     Return TF_ReturnOutPut(OW, Text, FileName, 0)
    }
```

Comment: Modifying the .ahk file which contains a running script's code has no effect on the running script.

Comment: @0x464e I believe that, myself, but there might be some edge case where it does not hold up according to my roommate's memory so I hope to leave that aspect of the inquiry in for a while to see if anyone has more info. I thought maybe if the script reads variables from the file, it will behave differently if the file is re-saved, even if the script is not re-loaded.

Comment: I think this can be pretty complicated because I have had a lot of trouble finding accepted answers about filewrite on the AHK forums. And there are many ways to do things. Sometimes they write the whole script to a variable then overwrite the entire file, other times they only overwrite one line.

Comment: The .ahk file only contains code, which is passed to the AHK interpreter. You'd have to reload the script to make any changes take effect. In any case, I don't think there is any real reason whatsoever to have to make some changes to the script's code during runtime. Maybe you could try to explain what your actual end goal is, I could give suggestions. The simplest real solution would be just a config file that gets read from. A proper communication solution with the running script would be using some actual interface, the simplest of which would (imo) be a shellhook for window messages.

Comment: @0x464e The actual end goal is to change the code of the script via the script (self-modifying code). It is okay to reload the script. I see no reason the file should not be easy to edit just like any other file. There are many examples of self-modifying code online, I think. It keeps everything in one file. I hope the code will change all instances of the olddirectory name to the newdirectory name which is extracted from the InputBox.

Comment: The real solution for this is to have a config file where from where you read this config value.

Comment: @0x464e I suppose it could be. "Any which way you can". I prefer to have self-modifying code for all of the reasons stated above and more. But this type of stylistic debate is meaningless for such a small example. The only tangible difference between using a config file or using self-modifying code in this situation is the need to reload the script after the function's execution on the one hand and the extra file on the other hand. At the end of the day, I can't edit any file (neither a config file nor a script file), and unless you're talking about JSON libs or INI-write, I can't edit a file.

Comment: @0x464e You can see that forum threads on either topic, even going back 17 years, are really just dead ends: https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/8366-self-editing-script/ . This user recommends config files but has no working method, also, for example. It's possible that AHK cannot edit files well. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a hotkey to toggle the values without changing the file itself.

```
#SingleInstance Force
^d::
    Gosub, toggle    ; change var(this is needed because in the first run, "var" is blank)
    InputBox, oldDir, Edit AHK File, Insert OLD directory name., , 300, 140, , , , ,% var
    If ErrorLevel
        Return
    Gosub, toggle    ; change var
    InputBox, newDir, Edit AHK File, Insert NEW directory name., , 300, 140, , , , ,% var
    If ErrorLevel
        Return
    Return

^t::    ; Ctrl+t to invert the values C:\test and C:\new
    toggle:
        toggle := !toggle
        var := toggle ? "C:\test" : "C:\new"
    Return
```

Your default values was not showing, because in your code there's a missing comma in inputbox parameters

```
InputBox, OutputVar , Title, Prompt, HIDE, Width, Height, X, Y, Locale, Timeout, Default
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help. 

But I also hope other answerers know:

the desired result is to update the .ahk file that is running.

So, there should be a fileread, filewrite, and strreplace or regexreplace or 

something. 

In other words, the end result will persist between sessions....

Because it is self-modifying code.

Answer (score 0):

## Ini version

```
!u::
FileCreateDir, %A_ScriptDir%\config
FileAppend, `n, %ftConfig%
IniWrite, c:\test, %ftConfig%, paths, u
Return
```

### Self-Editing-Code Version

```
; HELLO
f := FileOpen(A_ScriptFullPath,  "r")
text := f.read()
f.close()

text := StrReplace(text, "HELLO", "WORLD")
FileDelete, % A_ScriptFullPath
f := fileOpen(A_ScriptFullPath, "w")
f.write(text)
f.close()
return
```

This is all v1.